# Floating exception point al ingresar calificaciones en arreglos de estructuras

Tags: c++

Este programa es una tarea sobre crear un reporte de calificaciones para cada alumno, pero al momento de llegar a ingresar la primera calificación el programa se detiene y muestra el siguiente error: terminated by signal SIGFPE (Floating point exception). Uso Visual Studio Code en macOS Big Sur 11.2.3

Cualquier parte del código que pueda mejorar por favor háganmelo saber.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#define MAXCHAR 50
#define MAXCALIF 8
#define MAXALUM 40

struct Alumno{
    char nom_alumno[MAXCHAR];
    char ape_alumno[MAXCHAR];
    char expediente[MAXCHAR];
    float calif[MAXCALIF];
    float prom_alumno;
};

struct Grupo{
    char clave_grupo[MAXCHAR];
    char nom_materia[MAXCHAR];
    int num_calif;
    int num_alumnos;
    Alumno lista_alumnos[MAXALUM];
    float prom_general;
};

struct Profesor{
    char nom_profesor[MAXCHAR];
    char num_empleado[MAXCHAR];
    int num_materias;
    Grupo lista_grupos[MAXCALIF];
};

int main()
{
    int aux;
    Profesor profesores;

    cout << "\nBienvenido al reporte de calificaciones" << endl;

    cout << "\nNombre y apellido del profesor: ";
    cin.getline(profesores.nom_profesor,MAXCHAR);

    cout << "\nNumero de empleado: ";
    cin.getline(profesores.num_empleado,MAXCHAR);

    cout << "\nNumero de materias: ";
    cin >> profesores.num_materias;

    int num_grup;
    cout << "\nNumero de grupos: ";
    cin >> num_grup;

    cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_grup; i++)
    {
        cout << "Clave del grupo " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin.getline(profesores.lista_grupos[i].clave_grupo, MAXCHAR);
        cout << "Nombre de la materia: ";
        cin.getline(profesores.lista_grupos[i].nom_materia, MAXCHAR);
        cout << "Numero de calificaciones: ";
        cin >> profesores.lista_grupos[i].num_calif;
        cout << "Numero de alumnos: ";
        cin >> profesores.lista_grupos[i].num_alumnos;
        for(int j = 0; j < profesores.lista_grupos[i].num_alumnos; j++)
        {
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Nombre del alumno " << j+1 << ": ";
            cin.getline(profesores.lista_grupos[i].lista_alumnos[j].nom_alumno, MAXCHAR);
            cout << "Apellido del alumno " << j+1 << ": ";
            cin.getline(profesores.lista_grupos[i].lista_alumnos[j].ape_alumno, MAXCHAR);
            cout << "Expediente del alumno " << j+1 << ": ";
            cin.getline(profesores.lista_grupos[i].lista_alumnos[j].expediente, MAXCHAR);

            for (int k = 0; k < profesores.lista_grupos[i].num_calif; i++)
            {
                cout << "Calificacion " << k+1 << " del alumno " << j+1 << ": ";
                cin >> profesores.lista_grupos[i].lista_alumnos[j].calif[k];
                aux += profesores.lista_grupos[i].lista_alumnos[j].calif[k];
            }
            profesores.lista_grupos[i].lista_alumnos[j].prom_alumno = aux/profesores.lista_grupos[i].num_calif;;
        }
    }

    cout << "Profesor(a): " << profesores.nom_profesor;
    cout << "Numero de empleado: " << profesores.num_empleado;
    cout << "Numero de grupos: " << num_grup;

    cout << "Numero de expediente" << setw(5) << "Nombre del alumno" << setw(5) << "Promedio" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_grup; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < profesores.lista_grupos[i].num_alumnos; j++)
        {
            cout << profesores.lista_grupos[i].lista_alumnos[j].expediente;
            cout << setw(5) << profesores.lista_grupos[i].lista_alumnos[j].nom_alumno;
            cout << setw(5) << profesores.lista_grupos[i].lista_alumnos[j].prom_alumno;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Datos de entrada:

Bienvenido al reporte de calificaciones

Nombre y apellido del profesor: Profesor

Numero de empleado: 3090018

Numero de materias: 3

Numero de grupos: 2

Clave del grupo 1: A

Nombre de la materia: Modulo 1

Numero de calificaciones: 3

Numero de alumnos: 3

Nombre del alumno 1: Jose

Apellido del alumno 1: Felix

Expediente del alumno 1: 22022121

Calificacion 1 del alumno 1: 10

Error: terminated by signal SIGFPE (Floating point exception)

Comment: Si dejas ejemplos de los valores que introduces al programa y del valor en el que produce el error ayudará a tener una pista de por dónde va el problema.

Comment: Al correrlo yo me sale que en algun punto estas haciendo una division por 0. Y como nota, `aux` no tiene un valor inicial cuando empiezas a hacer `aux += ...`, asi que los resultados que te de eso probablemente sean numeros basura.

Answer (score 1):

`SIGFPE` es una señal de error que indica una excepción en un cálculo aritmético en coma flotante (*`SIG`nal `F`loating `P`oint `E`xception*), si consultamos [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/SIG_types) (traducción mía):

| Constante | Explicación |
| --- | --- |
| `SIGTERM` | Petición de terminar el programa |
| `SIGSEGV` | Acceso inválido a memoria (violación de segmento) |
| `SIGINT` | Interrupción externa, normalmente iniciada por el usuario |
| `SIGILL` | Imagen de programa inválida, una instrucción inválida por ejemplo |
| `SIGABRT` | Una condición de terminación anormal, por ejemplo una llamada a `std::abort()` |
| `SIGFPE` | Operación aritmética errónea, como dividir entre cero |

Lo más común es recibir esta señal de error al dividir entre cero, pero puede darse también al sobrepasar los límites del tipo de datos ya sea por encima (*overflow*) o por debajo (*underflow*).

En tu caso, lo que seguramente ha sucedido es que has incurrido en [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) por estar operando con una variable que no ha sido inicializada. En tu caso usas `aux` como numerador de una división:

```
aux/profesores.lista_grupos[i].num_calif;;
```

Y esta variable no ha sido inicializada antes de operar con ella:

```
int aux;
```

Prueba inicializarla a cero ya sea explícitamente:

```
int aux = 0;
```

O con inicialización por defecto:

```
int aux{};
```